# Como colocar paramentros para renomear aquivos no powershell?

Tags: powershell, arquivo-zip

Estou tentando modificar o nome de um item no powershell, o problema é o seguinte:

existe varios arquivos com esses nomes
V0185M03.D15
C0185M03.D15
B0185M03.D15

inicialmente eu quero zipar todos esses acquivos com o codigo "0185" para "01851503.zip"
onde o "M" é o mês e ".D15" é o dia
o nome do aquivos tem que ficar "CodigoDiaMes"
eu ja fiz um meio codigo que ficou assim

Compress-Archive -Path "c:\codigos*0185* -destination "c:\codigos\0185.zip"

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: O código tem sempre 4 digitos ou isso pode variar?

Comment: Pode ser também um arquivo bat ou tem que ser powershell?

Comment: Os dados estão sempre na posição exata como aparecem ai por exemplo código posição 2-5 (contando da esquerda) mês 7-8 dia 11-12 ?

Comment: Depois de zippados os arquivos originais devem ser deletados ou não?

Comment: Desculpa a demora Ricardo, mas vou responder agora
Sim, o código tem sempre 4 dígitos.
Eu prefiro powershell pq estou estudando a linguagem.
Sim, sempre são gerados nessa exata ordem.
Devem ser movidos para uma pasta com nome "Backup" mas só os arquivos .D (que eu ja consegui fazer).

Answer (score -2):

Olá amigo parece que ficou faltando uma aspa após a fonte:

```
Compress-Archive -Path "c:\codigos*0185*" -destination "c:\codigos\0185.zip"
```

Aqui está o código de um arquivo batch que chama o powershell para zipar os arquivos:

```
@echo off
:: Informe o caminho para os codigos aqui:
set Fonte=Codigos
pushd "%Fonte%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do call :Zippar "%%~a"
powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "%~dp0power.ps1"
del /q "%~dp0power.ps1
exit

:Zippar
set Codigo=%~1
set C4=%Codigo:~1,4%
set Mes=%Codigo:~6,2%
set Dia=%Codigo:~10,2%
echo compress-archive '%Codigo%' '%C4%%Dia%%Mes%.zip'>>"%~dp0power.ps1"
echo remove-item '%Codigo%'>>"%~dp0power.ps1"
goto :EOF
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]